# "VM Exception while processing transaction: revert" when using OpenZeppelin ERC721 mint in truffle console

Tags: ethereum, solidity, web3js

I am using OpenZeppelin's ERC721 with the simple mint function. However, I get `VM Exception while processing transaction: revert` when I call the function in `truffle console`

I first open up Ganache, and then I migrate `truffle migrate --reset`. Then, I `truffle console`, then I set up the contract `SimpleStorage.deployed().then((instance)=>{app=instance})`. Finally I call the function and get the error `app.buyOneToken`

Here is my SimpleStorage.sol

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.6.0;

import './MyToken.sol';

contract SimpleStorage {

  //The ERC721 token
  MyToken public myToken;
  uint256 public tokenId;

  constructor (MyToken _myToken) public {
    myToken = _myToken;
    tokenId=0;
  }

  function buyOneToken() public payable {
    myToken.addMinter(msg.sender);
    require(myToken.mint(msg.sender, tokenId));
    tokenId++;
  }
}
```

Here is MyToken.sol

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.6.0;

import 'openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Full.sol';
import 'openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721Mintable.sol';

contract MyToken is ERC721Full, ERC721Mintable{

  string name;
  string symbol;

  constructor (string memory _name, string memory _symbol) public 
ERC721Full(_name, _symbol) {
     // solhint-disable-previous-line no-empty-blocks
     name=_name;
     symbol=_symbol;
  }
}
```

Here is the migration for both .sol files, 2_deploy_contracts.js

```
var SimpleStorage = artifacts.require("./SimpleStorage.sol");
var MyToken = artifacts.require("./MyToken.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  const _name = "Like Token";
  const _symbol = "LIKE";
  deployer.deploy(MyToken, _name, _symbol).then(function(){
    return deployer.deploy(SimpleStorage, MyToken.address);
  });
};
```

I have a modified version where I only migrate `MyToken.sol` (which has access to OpenZeppelin's ERC721 library). I can mint a token fine then. However, when I follow the procedure outlined above after migration and using the truffle console to call the function, I get the error.

Answer (score 1):

`ERC721Mintable.mint` has an `onlyMinter` modifier.

Try adding a minter address and then calling mint from this address.

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the core issue. However, after I add the `addMinter()` function, it still reverts. I am wondering, do I need to somehow declare and admin account that can only add certain minters? (Note: I've edited my function to include addMinter())

Comment: Your contract is trying to `addMinter()`, but only a minter is allowed to do that. When you create the token in the first place, only you (the one who created the contract) is a minter. So *you* need to call `addMinter()` and pass in the address of your contract (SimpleStorage).

Comment: @smarx Yes, that did the trick. In truffle console, I just got an instance of MyToken to pass in the address of SimleStorage to addMinter()